# VS2015 - Local fields/references reset to null after edit and continue?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, edit-and-continue

For a particular large solution/project I'm working on, I've noticed if I do an edit and continue all the local fields & references in the method where I did the change will be reset to null.

I've quickly checked this with a small console application and it works as expected (references are maintained after edit/continue), so I'm guessing it's something to the with the large solution/project rather than my Visual Studio 2015 installation.

Any ideas what the problem could be?